# What is the difference between 0:: and 0: when filtering a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, kaggle

I am trying to follow the [Kaggle Titanic tutorial](https://www.kaggle.com/c/titanic/details/getting-started-with-python) that is solving the problem using Python and NumPy. I am having difficulties understanding what is the difference between data[0::, ] and data[0:, ]. I copy paste the relevant code snippet below:

```
for i in xrange(number_of_classes):       #loop through each class
    for j in xrange(number_of_price_brackets):   #loop through each price bin

        women_only_stats = data[                          # Which element           
                                (data[0::, 4] == "female") &   # is a female and
                                (data[0::, 2].astype(np.float) # was ith class
                                  == i+1) 
                                &                              # and
                                (data[0:, 9].astype(np.float)  # was greater
                                  >= j * fare_bracket_size)    # than this bin 
                                &                              # and
                               (data[0:, 9].astype(np.float)   # less than
                                  < (j+1)*fare_bracket_size)   # the next bin    
                               , 1]                        # in the 2nd col
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect there to be *any* difference, have you tried switching to see if the result changes? Both are using the default `stop` and `step` in the slice.

Comment: @wim ah that's true, the tutorial is using 2.7. Does `numpy` actually do that, though?

Comment: No, I was mistaken, because it is always getitem with a tuple in the OP's case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no difference, both methods will hook into `__getitem__` in the same way.

```
>>> class Thing(object):
...     def __getitem__(self, item):
...         print(repr(item))
...
>>> t = Thing()
>>> t[0:, 4]
(slice(0, None, None), 4)
>>> t[0::, 4]
(slice(0, None, None), 4)
```

Comment: So there would be no harm to use 0:: instead of 0: